# Uncertainty principle

Tags: momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavelength

I am reading about [uncertainity principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). 
My textbook says, if $λ$ is the wavelength of the radiation used to observe the particle then the position of the particle cannot be determined with accuracy greater than ±λ.

What does it means? What does Wavelength have to with size of The particle?

Comment: better read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables

Comment: It means that you have a really bad textbook. The uncertainty principle has nothing to do with the resolution of the measurement device, neither is a measurement with light of wavelength $\lambda$ limited to that precision. You can buy plenty of super-resolution microscopes for e.g. biological applications that exceed this limit by almost an order of magnitude and the chips in your computer were made with lithography techniques that also exceed that limit greatly.

Comment: The textbook is discussion spatial resolution, not the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. If it's labeling the former as the latter, that's a major error.

Comment: its not one book ..... but Others are mentioning the same. It is talking about physical significance of the law! which is also called as Observer's Effect (not sure)

Answer (score 1):

In quantum mechanics observables are represented by (some classes) of self-adjoint operators on some Hilbert space. Saying that you can precisely measure a quantity given by the operator $A$ means that your state can be one of the eigenstates of that operator. Likewise, if you want to precisely measure two quantities $A, B$ together your state needs to be an eigenstate of *both* operators at once. It can be proven that two operators may have a common set of eigenstates (and therefore possible measurements) if and only if they commute. As a consequence, if you have a set of mutually non-commuting operators you cannot have common eigenstates and ergo you cannot precisely measure the two quantities together (because in order to do so you **must** have at least one common eigenstate).

Do **not** approach the uncertainty principle the way your textbook does, because it is wrong in many respects: in particular

- you cannot measure the position of the particle at all, anyway, because the position operator in quantum mechanics does **not** possess normalisable eigenstates belonging to any Hilbert space, no matter what other quantities you want to measure, no matter whether you are measuring its momentum at the same time.
- the example in your textbook is probably related to some sort of slit experiment where you can relate the radiation $\lambda$ of the particle to the angular dependence of your instrument, which happens to be kind of $\pm \lambda$. This has nothing to do with the uncertainty principle because it is an *experimental* error depending on how you build your apparatus. In quantum mechanics instead, the uncertainty is a theoretical definition of measurements.
- usually what such exercises do is to calculate the product of the momentum of the particle times its angular position (given in terms of $\lambda$) and compare it to $\hbar$, thus realising the two contributions cannot be zero together; but again, this is an experimental trick used to (wrongly) justify a theoretical definition.

When thinking about uncertainty always take as an example the angular momentum as a vector whose components $L_x, L_y, L_z$ satisfy non-zero commutation relations between each other:
$$
[L_i, L_j] = i\,\hbar\,\epsilon_{ijk} L_k
$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ are structure constants in some Lie algebra (in this case $\textrm{su}(2)$). The product of the errors on the measurements of two such operators in proportional to their non-zero commutator, hence neither of them can be zero (otherwise their commutator must be).

Comment: Actually it is Talking about Physical significance. "that smaller the wavelength .... more is uncertainity!